# xCode 4.2, iPhone 3.1.3, UITapGestureRecognizer, setNumberOfTapsRequired, unrecognized selector

Tags: xcode4.2, uitapgesturerecognizer, iphone-sdk-3.1.3

I'm trying to run xCode 4.2 using an iPhone 3.1.3. My quick question is:

- Is there a workaround to make this function work?

  ```
  UITapGestureRecognizer *gestureSingleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(didSingleTap:)];
  [gestureSingleTap setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
  [taskScrollView addGestureRecognizer:gestureSingleTap];
  [gestureSingleTap release];
  ```
- The error I'm getting at run-time is this:

  ```
  -[UITapGestureRecognizer setNumberOfTapsRequired:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x143170
  ```

My questions:

- Is there a workaround for this on iOS3.1.3 that is simple and does not require a large amount of code rewrite?
- Can the function be "extended" in some way to redirect to a 3.1.3 equivalent for backwards compatibility?

Many thanks!

Added note: found out some functions are considered "private" and not fully functional before their actual releases. This is probably my core issue. If anyone has a backwards compatibility library, I'd be interested to use that.

Comment: Added note: I did a lot of digging. Looks like 3.1.3 is not considered iOS 3.2. The basic functions are these for 3.1.3 but are considered "undocumented features" by apple in 3.1.3. They made the full introduction in iOS 3.2.

Comment: I'm going to leave the question open because there might be an way around this or a class extension that completes the missing functionality in 3.1.3. Very interested in backwards extending classes such as UITapGestureRecognizer+3.1.3compatibility.h

Comment: My workaround at the moment is to downgrade my xCode to 4.0.2 using a iPhone 3G (4.2.1) for development instead of an iPhone 2G (3.1.3).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the method `didSingleTap`:

Does it really have a semicolon after it and take an argument?  (also is it spelled correctly, and does your class actually define this method?)

If didSingleTap doesn't take arguments, it should be `@selector(didSingleTap)` (without the colon after `didSingleTap`).

Update: previous answer was wrong.  Properties define set/get methods.

Comment: Hi Michael, Thanks but it's still throwing the same error. I believe the property is internally translating it to "setNumberOfTapsRequired". Here the new code:
    gestureSingleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
Here's the error:
    -[UITapGestureRecognizer setNumberOfTapsRequired:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Comment: Okay, I updated my answer.  I now realize the unrecognized selector is not setNumberOfTapsRequired.